# Adding groups to autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I need to add groups to an already created autocomplete drop-down list in rails.  I'm not sure where to start and I'm not even sure if calling it "groups" is appropriate but I it has to look like the picture I've posted.  I would be very grateful if someone could at least point me in the right direction to get started.

http://imgur.com/XLYzeKa

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can add an enum field to your table of sentences for types (noun and verb) or add a model for types if sentence may has both of types.

After that you can select nouns and verbs separately and make a hash like `{ nouns: array_of_nouns, verbs: array_of_verbs }` and send it to your JavaScript, where you can search in two separate arrays.

Also you can use hashes instead of arrays and group sentences by first letter to speed search up. For example if you have 'nouns' `r`, `react`, `ruby`, `ruby-on-rails` and `javascript`, your `hash_of_nouns` would be like `{ 'j' => [ 'javascript' ], 'r' => ['ruby', 'react', 'ruby-on-rails', 'r'] }`. After first character, entered by user, you can take array, and search in it. It will be much more faster with lots of data than simple `array_of_nouns`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The solution ended using catcomplete using this resource.  Thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698310/documentation-for-catcomplete

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

- to solve case sensitive in autocomplete query, create an index of *fieldname* which you want to apply autocomplete (so to querying as BINARY):

**#db/migrate/...AddIndexFieldnameToTablename**

```
def change
  add_index :tablename, :fieldname
end
```

- to solve groupping values, use **scope**

**#app/controller/yourtablenames_controller.rb**

```
autocomplete :tablename, :fieldname, scopes: [:scope_rule_name]
```

**#app/model/yourtablename.rb**

```
scope :scope_rule_name, -> {group :fieldname}
```

Concerning how to apply autocomplete for rails4, I've followed [this](https://codepen.io/asommer70/post/autocomplete-with-rails4-autocomplete) guide.